# Why this works in Lua? - for k, v in next, t, nil do print(k, v) end

Tags: lua, iterator

I just can not wrap my head around this working Lua snipplet.

This:

```
t = {'a', 'b', 'c'}
for k, v in next, t, nil do
  print(k, v)
end
```

Returns this:

```
1   a
2   b
3   c
```

Can someone explain,

- how [`next`](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#pdf-next) gets `t` as its parameter?
- how `t` is a valid `to` parameter for the `for`
- and why `nil` is required and accepted as a valid step?

Comment: it is rather k that gets next (numeric index at left) and v that gets t[k] (value on the right), don't know for the rest

Comment: Lua feeds `t` as argument for `next` while executing [generic "for" loop](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#3.3.5).  This is different from numeric "for" loop.

Comment: Yes, now I see. This is not a numeric for, but a generic. The `in next, t, nil` part gets evaluated as `next(t, nil)` that now suddenly makes sense... Thanks Egor.

Comment: And you can also leave nil out completely: `for k, v in next, t do print(k, v) end`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To expand a bit on the other answers:

A more descriptive naming of the values involved in a 'generic for loop' is the following:

```
for k, v1, v2, … in f_step, state, k0 do  …  end
```

and it goes in a loop like

```
k,v1,v2,…=f_step(state,k0) ; if k==nil then break end ; k0=k ; --(…for body here…)
k,v1,v2,…=f_step(state,k0) ; if k==nil then break end ; k0=k ; --(…for body here…)
k,v1,v2,…=f_step(state,k0) ; if k==nil then break end ; k0=k ; --(…for body here…)
…
```

and f_step is free to modify `state` in any way it likes (though `pairs`/`next` don't do that, and as yet another example, `string.gmatch` even ignores both `state` *and* `k` entirely and keeps all varying state in a closure (think 'function' if you don't know that term yet) instead.)

---

Now, what `pairs` does is essentially just

```
function pairs( t )
    -- (__pairs logic goes here, omitted for brevity)
    return next, t, nil
end
```

and the common

```
for k, v in pairs( t ) do  …  end
```

essentially expands to

```
for k, v in next, t, nil do  …  end
```

(unless `t` has a metatable with `__pairs`.)

Now there's two reasons why you might explicitly write `next, t, nil` instead of `pairs` – to confuse people who don't know about this yet, or to avoid triggering `__pairs`.  (To avoid triggering `__index`/`__newindex`, you have `rawget`/`rawset`, to avoid `__pairs`, you explicitly write `next, t, nil`.  Or maybe you define `function rawpairs( t )  return next, t, nil  end` and use that…)

Answer (score 2):

All credits go to [Egor](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1847592/egor-skriptunoff) for his answer among the comments.

From the [Lua 5.3 manual](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#3.3.5):

> A for statement like
>
> ```
>  for var_1, ···, var_n in explist do block end
> ```
>
> is equivalent to the code:
>
> ```
>  do
>    local f, s, var = explist
>    while true do
>      local var_1, ···, var_n = f(s, var)
>      if var_1 == nil then break end
>      var = var_1
>      block
>    end
>  end
> ```

So the original statement translates into an infinite `while` loop, that keeps calling `next()` with initial parameters `next(t, nil)`, and in each iteration the second parameter is replaced by the next index in the `t` table. When finally `next(t, index_n)` returns `nil`, the loop breaks.

This seems to me an extremely powerful way to traverse a table, as `next()` can be replaced by pretty much any function giving full control over the iteration. Wow.